# Google TV - Trouble relaying channel digits with Anymote through Vizio Co-Star remote

Tags: google-tv

I'm working on a remote app running on Android phones using the Anymote library. It handles channel changing by sending digits to the digital tuner box via the GTV box's IR Blaster. In the case of the Vizio Co-Star, there is no IR blaster, but the user can use the unit's accompanying physical remote as an IR relay to control the TV / Digital tuner / etc. In this case, the volume commands and Guide command are relaying from the remote correctly, but when I try to send channel digits from the app through the Vizio box and physical remote to the cable company's digital tuner, the digits do not send, or the tuner only gets a zero. Does the Vizio's unique setup require a different way of sending the digits from Anymote than other GTV boxes?

Thanks in advance.
M-A Kuttner

Comment: This question doesn't belong here - you should ask it on http://superuser.com

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't belong - perhaps I didn't describe clearly enough. I'm wondering if this is a problem with the Anymote protocol API provided by Google, which I'm using within an app that I am developing. While I suspect the problem may be related to hardware configs, I believe other developers may have figured out a software workaround to this issue, which is why I've asked here.

Comment: questions about general computing and hardware should be not asked on stackoverflow - here you should work with some code, preferably. Just ask your question on superuser - it's a part of stackexchange network.

Comment: Or possibly http://programmers.stackexchange.com suits better.